# Vertical align of text

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

Here is image of my problem: http://i48.tinypic.com/2roszr9.jpg .
I want to ask you if you know how to center number in blue box, to be in the middle of green one. So if is text in green box longer, i want to center number of title in the middle of this text.  Here is the code:

```
<style>
.right-content-text {
    width: 235px;
}
.right-content-text p {
    background: red;
    float: left;
    width: 235px;
    height: auto;
}
span.index {
    background: blue;
    width: 35px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #373A40;
    font-weight: bold;
}
span.text {
    width:200px;
    background: green;
    vertical-align:middle;
    float: right;


}
span.text a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #373A40;

}   
</style>
<div class="right-content-text">
    <p><span class="index">2.</span><span class="text"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></span><div class="clear"></div></p>
    <p><span class="index">3.</span><span class="text"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</a></span><div class="clear"></div></p>
    <p><span class="index">4.</span><span class="text"><a href="#">Pellentesque aliquet pulvinar tortor, sed pretium nisl mollis eget. </a></span><div class="clear"></div></p>
    <p><span class="index">5.</span><span class="text"><a href="#">Fusce vestibulum molestie quam, et lacinia nibh egestas quis.</a></span><div class="clear"></div></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey now you can used

`display: table-cell;` in your text class.

```
span.index {
    background: blue;
    width: 35px;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;

    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #373A40;
    font-weight: bold;
}
span.text {
    width:200px;
    background: green;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;



}
```

**Live demo** http://jsfiddle.net/EHM5p/

Comment: i put your code to text class in css 
`span.text {
 width:200px;
 background: green;
 vertical-align:middle;
 float: right;
 
 display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
 
}`